# On OSX, Grunt-Watch triggers whenever a file is opened. What is causing this?

Tags: macos, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

A grunt-watch change event is triggered any time I open a watched file. It doesn't matter what IDE I use (Coda, Text Edit, Eclipse), the change event always fires.

Is it possible OSX is editing the contents of the file in such a way that grunt-watch is picking up the change? Hopefully I am not the only person who has ever experienced this issue.

OSX 10.13.1 High Sierra, using the following deps together:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "^1.0.2",
  "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.3.0",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
  "grunt-env": "^0.4.4",
  "grunt-express-server": "^0.5.3"
}

watch: {
  JSlibs: {
    files: ['src/js/_components/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['uglify:libs'],
    options:{
      livereload:true
    }
  },
  JSapp:{
    files: ['src/js/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['uglify:app'],
    options:{
      livereload:true
    }
  },
  LESSlibs: {
    files: ['src/js/_components/**/*.css'],
    tasks: ['less:libs'],
    options:{
      livereload:true
    }
  },
  LESSapp: {
    files: ['src/css/**/*.less'],
    tasks: ['less:app'],
    options:{
      livereload:true
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Does changing the `files` property of the `JSLibs` target to `['src/js/_components/**/*.js']` _(i.e. appending `.js` to the glob pattern)_ resolve the issue? You could also try adding a `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` event listener to your `Gruntfile.js` like [this one](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-the-watch-event) to help debug what's causing it to trigger.

Comment: @RobC unfortunately no. I tried adding the .on event, it didn't give me much to go on:

JSapp: src/js/controllers/blog.js changed
>> File "src/js/controllers/blog.js" changed.

Comment: I assume you actually saved `src/js/controllers/blog.js` - hence the event log? Or, did that just occur independently? I'm unable to reproduce the issue with your config. I use an earlier version of macOS and it runs successfully here. There's certainly nothing wrong with your config. Perhaps a specific issue with High Sierra. For a `watch` event to fire a file must be [touch](https://ss64.com/bash/touch.html)'ed. Perhaps another OS process is touching the file(s), or the editor(s) used are set to auto-save perhaps. Do the `.js` file(s) modified date automatically get changed unassisted too?

Comment: @Robc This happens if I open any watched file using any application... even TextEdit. At this point I'm convinced it's High Sierra, because this did not happen on my older laptop. Unfortunately I haven't had much luck on Google.